# (Understrap) Wordpress Blog - Using Card Deck for Displaying Blog Posts, [Possible Flex Issue?]

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap-4

Currently I'm using Understrap to create a site with wordpress using the Bootstrap 4 Framework. I'm trying to create a nice blog grid rather than just a bog standard post loop.

To achieve my desired result I'm using the BS4 '[Card Deck](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/card/)'. However I seem to be getting some rather weird results with flex. I'm wondering if anyone has encountered this or can see anything obvious with my code that might be causing the error?

> Below is the code I have tweaked and their corresponding files.

**Content.php**

```
<?php
 /**
 * Post rendering content according to caller of get_template_part.
 *
 * @package understrap
 */ 
?>

<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="card">

<? $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full', false )[0] ?>

<img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo $thumb_url; ?>" alt="Card image cap">

<div class="card-body">

        <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h5 class="card-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ),
        '</a></h5>' ); ?>

        <?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <p class="card-text">
        <?php echo  get_the_excerpt(); ?>
    </p><!-- .entry-content -->

    <p class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">
            <?php understrap_posted_on(); ?>
            <?php understrap_entry_footer(); ?>
        </small>
    </p><!-- .entry-meta -->

</div><!-- <<< ITS IMPORTANT TO REMEMBER THIS -->

</div><!-- #post-## -->
```

**Index.php**

```
<main class="site-main" id="main">

  <!-- Introduce Bootstrap 4 Card Deck -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card-deck">

      <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

      <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>

      <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

      <?php

                        /*
                         * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                         * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                         * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                         */
                        get_template_part( 'loop-templates/content', get_post_format() );
                        ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php else : ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'loop-templates/content', 'none' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
    <!-- End Card Deck -->
  </div>

</main>
<!-- #main -->
```

*Disclaimer*
I don't usually dabble this deep in wp, so if you see anything noobish, that'll be why.

Thanks for the assist.
-B.

> **EDIT: 7 Sept 2018**
>
> Forgot to add the bloody `</div>`, that's two hours of my life I'll never get back. FML.

Answer (score 1):

With UnderStrap Version: 0.8.8, on WordPress 5.0+, you can do the following in your content.php file to get a BS4 Card template going...

```
<!--CARD-->
<article <?php post_class('card'); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

    <!--CARD THUMBNAIL-->
    <?php the_post_thumbnail($size, array('class' => 'car-img-top m-auto')); ?>

    <!--CARD BODY-->
    <div class="card-body">

        <!--CARD TITLE-->
        <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title card-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>

        <!--CARD TEXT-->
        <div class="card-text">
            <!--CONTENT-->
            <div class="entry-content">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php
                wp_link_pages( array(
                    'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'understrap' ),
                    'after'  => '</div>',
                ) );
                ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->

            <!--EXCERPT-->
            <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>

        </div>

        <!--FOOTER-->
        <footer class="entry-footer">
            <?php understrap_posted_on(); ?>
            <?php understrap_entry_footer(); ?>
            <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'understrap' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
        </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->

    </div>
    <!--END CARD BODY-->

</article><!-- #post-## -->
<!--END CARD-->
```

With this approach, you are keeping most of WordPress the same with its methods and properties, and also utilizing BootStrap on top of it. You could then style the BS4 elements on this page via SASS in the `sass/_theme.scss` file. This is one of the core strengths of UnderStrap.